# How to show comma seperated dates in radcalendar

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, telerik

I had a textbox, radCalendar and Button Control in my asp.net web page

when i select multiple dates in radcalender, i store it in textbox as 02-Sep-2015, 03-Sep-2015, 04-Sep-2015 dynamically as i select dates in radcalender dates added in textbox, check the code below :

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        On Error Resume Next

        Dim stringbuilder As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder
        For Each selecteddate As RadDate In RadCalendar1.SelectedDates
            stringbuilder.Append(selecteddate.Date.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy") + ", ")
        Next
        stringbuilder.Length -= 2
        TextBox1.Text = stringbuilder.ToString
    End Sub
```

What i want ?

i want if the textbox already had a multiples dates as 03-Sep-2015, 09-Sep-2015, 11-Sep-2015 on page_load event then the following dates are highlights in the radcalendar when page loads and rest all calendar dates are disabled.

Comment: i don't know vb, but you will get the logic, thankyou
you can try:

http://converter.telerik.com/

Answer (score 0):

If you are in `SelectionMode=Single` you can set selected date using calendar's `SelectedDate` property like:

```
RadCalendar calendar = new RadCalendar();  
calendar.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.Single;  
calendar.SelectedDate = new DateTime(2008, 7, 7);
```

For other `SelectionModes (Multiple and Extended)` you should use the calendar's `SelectedDates` property like:

```
RadCalendar calendar = new RadCalendar();  
calendar.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.Extended;  
calendar.SelectedDates.Add(new DateTime(2008, 7, 7));  
calendar.SelectedDates.Add(new DateTime(2008, 7, 8));  
calendar.SelectedDates.Add(new DateTime(2008, 10, 10));
```

**So do the following**:

```
if(Page.IsPostBack){
   if( String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(datestextbox.Text)==false)  //textbox in which dates as stored as comma separated
{
string[] datesToShow = datestextbox.Text.Split(',');
foreach (string date in datesToShow)
{
  yourCalendar.SelectedDates.Add(new DateTime (date )); 
}
}
}
```

Comment: error in last line

(New DateTime([date]))

Error- Value of type date cannot be converted to Telerik.web.UI.RadDate

Comment: `DateTime dt = new DateTime("");` is equal to `Dim dt As New DateTime("")`